# How to fix border prioritization with css "border-collapse: collapse" style in a table

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I am running into the issue that some borders have a higher priority than others when using the `border-collapse: collapse` styling in a table. For example when `border-right` on a cell is set it will have a higher priority and be shown on top of a `border-left`. Is there any way to set the `z-index` of a border or something to a similar effect?

I have attached a code snippet below to further illustrate what I mean.

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

td{
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#specialCell{
  border-right: 3px solid blue;
}

#otherSpecialCell{
  border-left: 4px solid green;
}

#redBorder{
  border-left: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td id="otherSpecialCell"> 1 </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td id="specialCell"> 2 </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<p>
The border on the "otherSpecialCell" has to be 4px large to be able to show up while the border on the "specialCell" only has to be 3px large before it shows up. (showing. that border-right has precidence over border-left)
</p>

<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td id="redBorder"> 3 </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<p> The red border is drawn above the top border aswell as the border along the middle of the table.</p>

<p>Is there any way to control any of this other than by changing the width of the borders?</p>
```

Additionally, I understand that I can get rid of the `border-collapse: collapse` styling and have a somewhat similar effect with setting left and right borders individually but the result is fairly unpleasing because of the triangular edges to the borders.

Comment: Question: are you able to change the HTML code (and add / change tags) or is that fixed, leaving you only CSS and JS to work with for styling?

Comment: When using 'border-collapse: collapse', the cell that appears first in the code will overcome the other. Its no a matter of 'border-right' and 'border-left' , but of cells order.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind seeing a little bit of black you can use `border-spacing: 0px;` instead of `border-collapse: collapse`.

```css
table{
  border-spacing: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

td{
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#specialCell{
  border-right: 3px solid blue;
}

#otherSpecialCell{
  border-left: 3px solid green;
}

#redBorder{
  border-left: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td id="otherSpecialCell"> 1 </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td id="specialCell"> 2 </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<p>
The border on the "otherSpecialCell" has to be 4px large to be able to show up while the border on the "specialCell" only has to be 3px large before it shows up. (showing. that border-right has precidence over border-left)
</p>

<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td id="redBorder"> 3 </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<p> The red border is drawn above the top border aswell as the border along the middle of the table.</p>

<p>Is there any way to control any of this other than by changing the width of the borders?</p>
```

Comment: That is a step in the right direction but I don't love the triangles that form when the borders come together in the corners. Thank you for the suggestion though.